# PHP Objects Overwriting problem

Tags: php, class, oop

here's my problem:

```
$Me[1] = new User(1);
$Me[2] = new User(2);
$Me[3] = new User(19);
$Me[4] = new User(75);
$Me[5] = new User(100);
foreach ($Me as $k) echo $k->getId();
```

I'm trying to create 5 users with, of course, different ID. The problem is that the User with ID 2 'overwrite' the User with ID 1, the User with ID 3 'overwrite' the User with ID 2, the User with ID 4 'overwrite' the User with ID 3, the User with ID 5 'overwrite' the User with ID 4.

I don't really know how to fix this, can anybody please help me?

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

I can't get the $id from the parent class. It seems like the last class initialized "overwrite" all the values (maybe becouse I declared it static? but how can I get it?)..

This is my class:

```
class User {
    public static $id;

    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }
}

class Sub extends User {
    public function __construct($id) {
    }

    public function printUserLink(){
            echo '<a href="userprofile.php?userid='.parent::getId().'">Go to user profile</a>';
    }
}
```

How do I get the Id in the "Sub" class?

Comment: Works for me. The error is somewhere else.

Comment: What is $me? has it been declared ?

Comment: What is the output of the pasted code?

Comment: That's a crystal clear case of Multiple Personality :)

Comment: You need to show your User class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the problem lies in your User class.  This simple example works as expected:

```
class User {
    private $id;

    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }
}

$Me[1] = new User(1);
$Me[2] = new User(2);
$Me[3] = new User(19);
$Me[4] = new User(75);
$Me[5] = new User(100);

foreach ($Me as $k) echo $k->getId() . "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
19
75
100
```

Without details of your User class (as suggested by ircmaxell), resolving the problem will be tricky.

Comment: I can't get the $id from the parent class. It seems like the last class initialized "overwrite" all the values (maybe becouse I declared it static? but how can I get it?)..
This is my class:

class User {
 public static $id;
 public function __construct($id) {
  $this->id = $id;
 }

 public function getId() {
  return $this->id;
 }
}
class Sub extends User {
 public function __construct($id) {}

 public function printUserLink(){
  echo '<a href="userprofile.php?userid='.parent::getId().'">Go to user profile</a>';
 }
}

How do I get the Id in the "Sub" class?

Comment: Yes, it will be because you have declared it as static (see [Static Member Variables](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/php/Static_Member_Variables.html)  for an use of static member variables). Why do you need it declared as static?

Comment: Becouse I don't know how to access it from a subclass (parent::$var doesn't work..) How can I do?